# web.config and app.config machine-specific settings in git

Tags: .net, git, configuration, web-config, app-config

We have multiple teams of developers in different offices, and they need different values for a number of configuration setting in our projects' `web.config` and `app.config` files.

We like to keep these configuration files checked in with a sensible set of default values, so that by checking out the trunk/master branch you have something working without needing to dig around for configuration files.

Historically we've used Subversion, and specifically TortoiseSVN, and this provided an easy way to manage local changes: We simply added these files to TortoiseSVN's automatic `ignore-on-commit` changelist. This prevents accidental checkin of these files, as you then need to select them specifically to include them on a checkin (and you can make sure you're checking in significant changes, not local-config noise). The main disadvantage of this approach is that the config files always look "changed", so it's not possible to at-a-glance know whether you have any local changes.

We're looking to switch to Git, and I'm trying to figure out the best approach.

First off, what's already there in other StackOverflow answers:

**Option 1: Check in xxx.sample files and .gitignore the actual config files**: This is recommended, for example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396645/74296). The main problem I see with this is that changes to the config file are easily forgotten, at two different points: The committer can easily miss changes that they need to add to the `.sample` file, and consumers (esp. continuous integration server) can easily miss changes that they need to incorporate from the `.sample` file into their local config file. So basically, that doesn't seem like a very good solution.

**Option 2: Have a checked-in xxx.defaults file and a .gitignored xxx.local config file which overrides any settings it defines**: This is offered up, fr example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1397180/74296). The issue there is that we're working with standard .Net configuration providers - I really don't want us to implement a whole new settings-loading framework when Mirosoft's already done all the work. Does anyone know a way to get app.config and web.config files to refer to optional local override files?

**Option 3: Have developers keep local branches, and then have them always check in cherry-picks or rebased branches into master, to always bypass/avoid the unwanted commits in their local branch**: This is offered as a possible workflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396886/74296), and while I appreciate the cleanliness of it in terms of change-tracking (everything checked in), it introduces a significant amount of *required* overhead on every single checkin; it's a major pain!

**Option 4: Have config files checked in, but have them marked with `--assume-unchanged`**: This is offered as a possible option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744071/74296); as far as I can tell it's very similar in spirit to the `ignore-on-commit` changelist in TortoiseSVN, except you have no visibility to these "hidden" changed files in a commit process; TortoiseGit, for example, does show the file with a "changed" icon overlay, but in the commit dialog the file does not show up at all. This seems a little frightening, again very easy to forget to check changes in.

Given these options, which are all the ones I've found, I'm really hoping for a way to optionally "include" a local config file into/over a checked-in app.config/web.config file and go with **option 2**; does anyone know of a way to do this, or other options that I'm missing? (I'm faintly tempted to consider a custom Xml-merging pre-build step...)

I should have mentioned earlier, we're still on VS2008, so Configuration Transforms are not available.

---

**UPDATE:** (deleted, was plain wrong)

**UPDATE 2:** I've deleted my previous update and answer, it was stupid / didn't work. I didn't realize that after an "ours" merge, the next merge in the other direction carries the "original" versions of those files back (overwrites the local branch changes); see edit history if you're interested. This question is as open as ever.

Comment: What approach did you end up taking? Thanks.

Comment: We ended up building an internal tool that I can't share without jumping through too many hoops to count. It simply supports placeholders in "template" files, which it converts to "final" files. Placeholder-to-Value mappings are stored in a pair of simple Xml docs, a "defaults" doc checked in and a "local" doc not checked in (.gitignored). The template files are checked in, but all the output files are .gitignored. It can run in "overwrite discrepancies" mode, or "warn about discrepancies" mode, where you want to use the final (eg web.config) file to update the corresponding template.

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to suggest you look at [ConfigGen](http://configgen.codeplex.com/).  We use it in all our projects, and it works wonders for all the developers and also for all our environments.  It basically runs off a spreadsheet that states machine name and output configuration file, and then tokenises a template App.Config or Web.Config, substituting values from the spreadsheet into it.  Add a simple pre-build step to your projects to run configgen, and before the build kicks off, you have a tailored configuration file for your machine.  It also supports default settings.

Take a look at the site and make your own mind up, but I can definitely vouch for it.

**EDIT**: It's worth noting that you can then ignore all your Web.config and App.config files (in terms of .git). But you do need to add your templates and spreadsheets to the repo.  Also, I am assured there is an update on the way that may well include an xml replacement for the spreadsheets, that has it's own editor, making it eminently more suitable for DVCS's.

**Edit2**: Also take a look at Daniel's post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8082937/186184.  He gives a very clear example of the template and spreadsheet, and how to get it working in your solution.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the simplest/most sensible solution, will go try it

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't downvote your answer ;) (especially since I have my own answer in this page)

Comment: ConfigGen now supports csv settings files as well as a global defaults setting file that allows you to store global settings in one file and merge them with a more specific settings file per app.

Answer (score 7):

Did you consider a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571358/what-is-the-right-way-to-maintain-a-version-for-the-server-with-only-config/10571580#10571580)?

[image: content filter dfriver]

That would mean, on each `git checkout`, the smudge script would *generate* the actual config file based on:

- a config template file (with config value placeholder like `@@A_PARAM_VALUE@@`)
- one of the config value file (each developer can keep versioned his/her own config file values)

That avoid any merge issue and gitignore settings: each "config value files" are different and remain separate.
This is also compatible with other config generation solution like [ConfigGen](http://configgen.codeplex.com/) mentioned in [pms1969](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186184/pms1969)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494548/6309).

Comment: hmm, this looks like fun - need to go play

Comment: OK, unless I'm misunderstanding something here, for this kind of flow to work we would need to establish a two-way content transformation; from checked-in to local (replacing placeholders, or building file contents from some single placeholder + template + values file), and from local to checked-in (replacing the in-place file/content with the original placeholder, based on some recognized part of the content). The nice thing is that it would be automatic on checkout (as long as you're using git and not something like libgit2?), but this looks much more complex than a custom build step...

Comment: @Tao Yes the '`clean`' script would be used if you need to store the local modification you have done on those generated file. And `libgit2` does support `smudge` (at least a little bit of smudge). Since, err... 4 days: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/197996

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [this answer for Managing complex Web.Config files between deployment environments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/435082/57787) by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50442/dan) for a potential solution. I use mercurial and use this same process to have a generic web.config file checked in and use the web transforms to change the location of `configSource` to point to my deployment specific stuff.

The advantage of using this route is it is completely built in to the framework, requires no extra code, and works with web deployment.

Checked in web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- snip -->
  <connectionStrings configSource="config/connectionStrings.config" />
</configuration>
```

Checked in web.debug.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings
      configSource="config/dev.connectionStrings.config"
      xdt:Transform="Replace(configSource)" />
</configuration>
```

I have a `config/connectionStrings.config` checked in with defaults, but the development servers `config/dev.connectionStrings.config` is not checked in and its not replaced on a new deployment.

Comment: This only works when you publish locally or to dev servers as debug, not when you're running within VS.

Comment: You could still apply the same logic just in reverse. Have the custom .config file specified in web.config and then use the transform files when publishing and then just do a `.gitignore` on the local config files. By using the `configSource` .Net will merge the different files together automatically without requiring additional code.

Comment: hmm, we're stuck on VS2008 and don't use web deployment (and have other non-ASP app components), but this `configSource` thing is food for thought anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar dilemma at our company. We ended up creating separate configuration branches which supplement the main branch. Like for example - develop-config, master-config, etc. We then have a small script which will rebase those branches with the correct source branch based on the deployment environment. So for example on the development machine we would rebase develop-config with develop. If you are working on local machine, you would get the default configuration (agreed upon by all developers) which is checked into the main branch (like the local DB name, password, etc). Of course the downside is that you always have to keep those *-config branches up-to-date or get them upto speed at the time of deployment.

Since implementing this workflow, I've come across couple of deployment tools out there like [whiskey_disk](https://github.com/flogic/whiskey_disk) which take a somewhat similar approach. In fact I like their solution a lot more since its much more secure and flexible. Although probably not a good fit for you guys since its geared more towards a LAMP/RoR development stack.

Aside from that, there are also some commercial solutions out there that you might want to take a look at like [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A bit has changed since 2012 and these days and now I would suggest your build/deploy tool (VS Team Services, TeamCity, Octopus Deploy) managing environment specific configurations.

If you work in azure you can define app settings and connection strings as part of your app definition.