# Can I create .config file and include it to web.config?

Tags: asp.net, config

Can I create .config file and include it to web.config?
How can i do this?

UPD.
If you want to separate config file, for example, move appSettings to another file you must do next: In web.config

```
  <appSettings configSource="myAppSettings.config" />
```

In myAppSettings.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do partially? I mean some settings belong to web.config whereas some from other config file?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you want to do, but all configuration sections can be stored in a separate files and be referenced by the main `.config` file using the [`configSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) property.

See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/04/26/using-configsource-to-split-configuration-files.aspx) blog post for details.

Answer (score 24):

This is the way to integrate multiple configs into one web.config

Code in web.config:

```
<appSettings configSource="config\appSettings.config"/>
<nlog configSource="config\nlog.config"/>
<applicationSettings>
        <MyApp.UI.Properties.Settings configSource="config\Settings.APGUI.config"/>
        <MyApp.BusinessServices.Properties.Settings configSource="config\Settings.Business.config"/>
        <MyApp.Auditing.Properties.Settings configSource="config\Settings.Auditing.config"/>
</applicationSettings>
```

more: [Managing complex Web.Config files between deployment environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428573/managing-complex-web-config-files-between-deployment-environments)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that often I want to be able have some app settings in one file and some app settings in another file, which isn't possible when using `configSource`.