# Creating app.config in C# ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

Im currently trying to create an application configuration file but the item doesn't seem to exist in that type of framework?
VS2013. This is what I do:

```
File -> New -> Proyect
C# -> ASP.NET Web Forms Application
Then, within the proyect -> Add New Item -> Filter by config
```

Only the web.config appears but not the app.config. Is it possible to create it? Or I just have to copy that file from another proyect and paste it?

Comment: well to break the news, in web applications it is called `web.config`, *not* `app.config`. Later one is for console/win-forms applications.

Comment: Can I create another web.config and reference it from the original web.config? I would like to separete web configurations from the application configuration that I may use.

Comment: Yes its possible further [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10300142/7324631)